# Python - Pandas writing blank files to file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python script that writes to several file formats via Pandas. It can write to CSV/JSON/HTML/Excel.

However for some reason the script is writing blank files. When I open the file this is what I see:

[image]

Before printing the file I am printing the dataframe to the screen output so I can validate that the data is there. For example with CSV the output to the screen is this:

```
    CSV data: ,AWS Account,Account Number,Name,Instance ID,AMI ID,Volumes,Private IP,Public IP,Private DNS,Availability Zone,VPC ID,Type,Key Pair Name,State,Launch Date
0,project-client-lab,123456789101,bastion001,i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,10.238.2.166,3.214.15.175,ip-10-238-2-166.ec2.internal,us-east-1a,vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,t3.small,project-client-int01,running,March 10 2020
1,project-client-lab,123456789101,logicmonitor001,i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,vol-0xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,10.238.2.52,,ip-10-238-2-52.ec2.internal,us-east-1a,vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,m5.large,project-client-int01,running,September 02 2019
2,project-client-lab,123456789101,project-cassandra001,i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,"vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",10.238.2.221,,ip-10-238-2-221.ec2.internal,us-east-1a,vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,m5.large,project-client-int01,running,January 14 2020
3,project-client-lab,123456789101,project-cassandra003,i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,"vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",10.238.2.207,,ip-10-238-2-207.ec2.internal,us-east-1a,vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,m5.large,project-client-int01,running,January 14 2020
4,project-client-lab,123456789101,project-cassandra003,i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,"vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",10.238.2.203,,ip-10-238-2-203.ec2.internal,us-east-1a,vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,c5.xlarge,project-client-int01,running,January 22 2020
5,project-client-lab,123456789101,project-cassandra001,i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,"vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",10.238.2.209,,ip-10-238-2-209.ec2.internal,us-east-1a,vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,c5.xlarge,project-client-int01,running,January 22 2020
6,project-client-lab,123456789101,haproxy001,i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,10.238.2.169,54.242.118.165,ip-10-238-2-169.ec2.internal,us-east-1a,vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,m5.large,project-client-int01,running,February 20 2020
7,project-client-lab,123456789101,logicmonitor002,i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,vol-0c48ff6ebb031008a,10.238.2.69,,ip-10-238-2-69.ec2.internal,us-east-1b,vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,m5.large,project-client-int01,running,September 13 2019
```

These are the functions that write to file:

```
def mongo_export_to_file(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number,instance_col=None,date=None):
    create_directories()
    if date == None:
        format= "%m-%d-%Y"
        today = datetime.today()
        today = today.strftime(format)
        date = today
    else:
        format= "%m-%d-%Y"
        date = datetime.strptime(date,"%m%d%Y")
        date = date.strftime(format)
    if not instance_col:
        _, _, instance_col = set_db()
    # make an API call to the MongoDB server
    if interactive == 0:
        mongo_docs = instance_col.find({})
    else:
        mongo_docs = instance_col.find({"Account Number": aws_account_number})
    # Convert the mongo docs to a DataFrame
    docs = pandas.DataFrame(mongo_docs)
    # Discard the Mongo ID for the documents
    docs.pop("_id")
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print("Choose a file format")
        print("1. CSV")
        print("2. JSON")
        print("3. HTML")
        print("4. Excel")
        choice = input("Enter a number 1-4: ")
        choice = int(choice)
    else:
        choice = 1
    if choice == 1:
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            # export MongoDB documents to CSV
            csv_export = docs.to_csv(sep=",") # CSV delimited by commas
            print ("\nCSV data:", csv_export)
        # Set the CSV output directory
        output_dir = os.path.join("..", "..", "output_files", "aws_instance_list", "csv", "")
        if interactive == 1:
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "aws-instance-list-" + aws_account + "-" + date +".csv")
        else:
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "aws-instance-master-list-" + date +".csv")

        # export MongoDB documents to a CSV file, leaving out the row "labels" (row numbers)
        docs.to_csv(output_file, ",", index=False) # CSV delimited by commas
    elif choice == 2:
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            json_export = docs.to_json() # return JSON data
            print ("\nJSON data:", json_export)
        # Set the JSON output directory
        output_dir = os.path.join("..", "..", "output_files", "aws_instance_list", "json", "")
        if interactive == 1:
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "aws-instance-list-" + aws_account + "-" + date +".json")
        else:
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "aws-instance-master-list-" + date +".json")
        # export MongoDB documents to a CSV file, leaving out the row "labels" (row numbers)
        docs.to_json(output_file)
    elif choice == 3:
        html_str = io.StringIO()
        # export as HTML
        docs.to_html(
        buf=html_str,
        classes="table table-striped"
        )
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            # print out the HTML table
            print (html_str.getvalue())
        # Set the HTML output directory
        output_dir = os.path.join("..", "..", "output_files", "aws_instance_list", "html", "")
        if interactive == 1:
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "aws-instance-list-" + aws_account + "-" + date +".html")
        else:
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "aws-instance-master-list-" + date + ".html")
        # save the MongoDB documents as an HTML table
        docs.to_html(output_file)
    elif choice == 4:
        # Set the Excel output directory
        output_dir = os.path.join("..", "..", "output_files", "aws_instance_list", "excel", "")
        time.sleep(5)
        if interactive == 1:
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "aws-instance-list-" + aws_account + "-" + date + ".xlsx")
        else:
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "aws-instance-master-list-" + date + ".xlsx")
        # export MongoDB documents to a Excel file, leaving out the row "labels" (row numbers)
        writer = ExcelWriter(output_file)
        docs.to_excel(writer,"EC2 List",index=False)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        exit = input("Exit program (y/n): ")
        if exit.lower() == "y" or exit.lower() == "yes":
            exit_program()
        else:
            main()


def print_reports(interactive,aws_account,aws_account_number):
    set_db(instance_col=None)
    inputDate = input("Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': ")
    day,month,year = inputDate.split('/')
    isValidDate = True
    try:
        datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
    except ValueError :
        isValidDate = False
        print_reports(interactive,aws_account,aws_account_number)

    if(isValidDate) :
        print(f"Input date is valid: {inputDate}")
        format= "%m%d%Y"
        inputDate = datetime.strptime(inputDate,"%m/%d/%Y")
        inputDate = inputDate.strftime(format)
    else:
        print(f"Input date is not valid: {inputDate}")
        print_reports(interactive,aws_account,aws_account_number)
    myclient = connect_db()
    mydb = myclient["aws_inventories"]
    instance_col = "ec2_list_" + inputDate
    instance_col = mydb[instance_col]
    mongo_export_to_file(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number,instance_col,date=inputDate)
```

This is [all my code](https://pastebin.com/ZQ5WABw4) in this script.

Why is this happening and how to I correct that?

Comment: In excel, go to data>from text/csv

Comment: I can't. When I do that all the commands in Excel are greyed out.  It must be something with the file.

Comment: I mean, separately open excel, without opening any file

Comment: Oh! Yeah that works. If I open excel first without clicking on a file, and then open the file from within Excel I can see the contents of my file. Weird! Any idea why the file is blank if I open it by double clicking in the file explorer?

Comment: I'm not sure, there might have been some issue with the formatting

Comment: I wrote my comment as an answer. If it worked, please mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the file in Excel by:

1. Opening Excel
2. Going to the "Data" tab
3. In the "Get & Transform Data" section, click "From Text/CSV"